# Changing the properties of a degrading font

Tags: fonts, webfonts, css

was wondering if this was possible.. Different Webfonts have different line heights which can change the dynamic of a webpage if your initial choice isn't present in the users browser. Is there a way to alter the properties of a backup font?

i.e changing the line-height of arial if the font degrades

```
 font-family: futura, arial;
```

could I alter the values of the arial font in css? or maybe in the values of line height itself?

i.e

```
   line-height: 14px, 19px;
```

*thanks*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible in CSS. This is a fundamental limitation in CSS: it treats properties as separate and does not let you set the value of one property depend on what happens to be end result of resolving the value of another property.

This implies that the fonts in a `font-family` list, or “font stack”, should be chosen so that they are fairly in terms of suitable line height, for example.

By not setting `line-height` at all, you would make browsers apply their own defaults, which are supposed to depend on the font. But the defaults might be unsuitable, depending on content and other aspects.